# Add a simple, date based tag versioning system

Tags: feature-request, tags, review

Very many tags on Stack Overflow (and other sites, cough Arqade cough) are based upon products. Products evolve over time though and a question asked about C# in 2009 is unlikely to receive the same answer today as the language gains in features and complexity while cruft is removed and other features just change with each release.

What I propose is a relatively simple mechanism where we can tell the site, look, c# got a major upgrade on August 15, 2012; answers before that might not be relevant to people using C# 5.0 — and conversely answers newer than that might not be helpful to people stuck in the past.

Once you have the milestones set, you can simply say: if a post was last active before a tag milestone, then it is probably not up to date. Otherwise it probably  is.

There are four parts here:

- For people who aren't using the latest and greatest, the possibility to view a read only snapshot on the question as it was before each milestone. I suppose you could use some sort of drop down here:

  > View question as of [ c# 4.0. | ⬇ ]
- For people who are using the latest and greatest, a one-line blurb calling out under which tag milestone / product era was the answer released:

  > This answer was contributed for debian **squeeze**. Proceed with caution.
- For answerers a review queue where users can see their own answers from previous milestones and are given the opportunity to say "looks good" or "edit", both of which retire the disclaimer (basically by bumping the last active timerstamp to after the milestone)
- For trusted users a way to define those milestones, perhaps through the tag wiki/suggested edit mechanism.

Comment: Of course you could go to town with this. Write posts for older versions; edit posts of older versions without affecting the current one in a git branch fashion; search by tag version; upvote a post in a version and downvote it in another; deal with questions about removed features intelligently somehow; etc. etc. etc. I think though that a simple time stamp based version would be the simplest thing that could work and it would work reasonably well.

Comment: This also wouldn't work very well on Ask Ubuntu where the entire site is about a single product... Also a potential culprit is Python, where 2.7 and 3.x sort of peacefully coexist as latest versions of their respective parallel universes. For those cases you could simply not use this feature though...

Comment: How would this work with betas and other early access before public release?  We have two officially supported versions, but welcome question about the upcoming version and try to help the poor souls on the outdated version.

Comment: @mpd somewhat poorly; for beta questions, I would expect that the question itself would mention the use of a beta, making the situation clear to the reader; even then, pre-release software is just that, pre-release, and what's released in the final version may differ.

Comment: I can't imagine how it could be expected to work. It simply doesn't make any sense. If the questions is about language or product feature in general, no automatic version tag is appropriate. If it's about specific feature for specific version, you should use proper version tag. In all cases, using a library, you should specify the version.

Comment: @luk how do you know in advance what is a version specific feature and what isn't? Do you have a crystal sphere that I can borrow?

Comment: Although I wrote this post with Stack Overflow in mind, the need for something to deal with this properly comes from Arqade (dealing with the bajillion revisions of Minecraft out there) and I can also see this being useful throughout the network, from Super User to Linux & Unix to Webapps.

Comment: @badp because in (maybe 90% maybe more) cases it isn't version specific. Why do you want to assume everything is version specific? Could you explain, what sense makes such versioning for Javascript, for example?

Comment: @Łukasz웃Lツ If it doesn't make sense for a tag, you just wouldn't use it there. I've already raised a similar concern for Python. Regardless, for "90% maybe more" answers that might remain valid after one major release, 10% of the other answers becomes wrong/outdated/irrelevant. This adds up as time passes.